# Gluon Mobile iOS Audio Player

Tags: javafx, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

Since the JavaFx Media has not been ported to the Mobile Platforms yet, can anyone help me with using the native iOS APi's to play a sound mp3 file that would be stored in my main/resources folder in my gluon project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While on Android we can easily add native API to the Android folders of a Gluon project (check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419634/javafxports-how-to-call-android-native-media-player) for using native Media on Android), the use of native code (Objetive-C) with the Media API on iOS folders is not enough, since it has to be compiled, and the compiled files have to be included into the ipa.

Currently, [Charm Down](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down) is doing this for a bunch of services. If you have a look at the `build.gradle` script for [iOS](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/tip/ios/build.gradle?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), it includes the `xcodebuild` task to compile and build the native library `libCharm.a`, that later should be included in any iOS project using any of those services.

My suggestion will be cloning Charm Down, and providing a new service: `AudioService`, with some basic methods like:

```
public interface AudioService {
    void play(String audioName);
    void pause();
    void resume();
    void stop(); 
}
```

This service will be added to the `Platform` class:

```
public abstract class Platform {
    ...
    public abstract AudioService getAudioService();
}
```

and you should provide implementations for Desktop (empty), Android (like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419634/javafxports-how-to-call-android-native-media-player)) and iOS.

**IOS implementation - Java**

You will have to add this to the `IOSPlatform` class:

```
public class IOSPlatform extends Platform {
    ...
    @Override
    public AudioService getAudioService() {
        if (audioService == null) {
            audioService = new IOSAudioService();
        }
        return audioService;
    }
}
```

and create the `IOSAudioService` class:

```
public class IOSAudioService implements AudioService {

    @Override
    public void play(String audioName) {
        CharmApplication.play(audioName);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        CharmApplication.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        CharmApplication.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        CharmApplication.stop();
    }
}
```

Finally, you will have to add the native calls in `CharmApplication`:

```
public class CharmApplication {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Charm");
        _initIDs();
    }
    ...
    public static native void play(String audioName);
    public static native void pause();
    public static native void resume();
    public static native void stop();
}
```

**IOS implementation - Objective-C**

Now, on the native folder, on `CharmApplication.m`, add the implementation of those calls:

```
#include "CharmApplication.h"
...
#include "Audio.h"

// Audio
Audio *_audio;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_gluonhq_charm_down_ios_CharmApplication_play
(JNIEnv *env, jclass jClass, jstring jTitle)
{
    NSLog(@"Play audio");
    const jchar *charsTitle = (*env)->GetStringChars(env, jTitle, NULL);
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(UniChar *)charsTitle length:(*env)->GetStringLength(env, jTitle)];
    (*env)->ReleaseStringChars(env, jTitle, charsTitle);

    _audio = [[Audio alloc] init];
    [_audio playAudio:name];
    return;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_gluonhq_charm_down_ios_CharmApplication_pause
(JNIEnv *env, jclass jClass)
{
    if (_audio) 
    {
        [_audio pauseAudio];
    }
    return;   
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_gluonhq_charm_down_ios_CharmApplication_resume
(JNIEnv *env, jclass jClass)
{
    if (_audio) 
    {
        [_audio resumeAudio];
    }
    return;   
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_gluonhq_charm_down_ios_CharmApplication_stop
(JNIEnv *env, jclass jClass)
{
    if (_audio) 
    {
        [_audio stopAudio];
    }
    return;   
}
```

and create the header file `Audio.h`:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Audio :UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
}
    - (void) playAudio: (NSString *) audioName;
    - (void) pauseAudio;
    - (void) resumeAudio;
    - (void) stopAudio;
@end
```

and the implementation `Audio.m`. This one is based on this [tutorial](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/10/01/tutorial-playing-audio-with-avaudioplayer/):

```
#include "Audio.h"
#include "CharmApplication.h"

@implementation Audio 

AVAudioPlayer* player;

- (void)playAudio:(NSString *) audioName 
{
    NSString* fileName = [audioName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSString* extension = [audioName pathExtension];

    NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName] withExtension:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",extension]];
    NSError* error = nil;

    if(player)
    {
        [player stop];
        player = nil;
    }

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if(!player)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    player.delegate = self;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];

}

- (void)pauseAudio
{
    if(!player)
    {
        return;
    }
    [player pause];
}

- (void)resumeAudio
{
    if(!player)
    {
        return;
    }
    [player play];
}

- (void)stopAudio
{
    if(!player)
    {
        return;
    }
    [player stop];
    player = nil;
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"%s successfully=%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, flag ? @"YES"  : @"NO");
}

- (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s error=%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
}

@end
```

**Build the native library**

Edit the `build.gradle` for the iOS module, and add the Audio service to the `xcodebuild` task:

```
def nativeSources = ["$project.projectDir/src/main/native/CharmApplication.m",
                     ...,
                     "$project.projectDir/src/main/native/Audio.m"]

...
def compileOutputs = [
                "$project.buildDir/native/$arch/CharmApplication.o",
                "$project.buildDir/native/$arch/Charm.o",
                 ...,
                "$project.buildDir/native/$arch/Audio.o"]
```

**Build the project**

Save the project, and from the root of the Charm Down project, on command line run:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

If everything is fine, you should have:

- Common/build/libs/charm-down-common-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- Desktop/build/libs/charm-down-desktop-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- Android/build/libs/charm-down-android-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- IOS/build/libs/charm-down-ios-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- IOS/build/native/libCharm.a

**Gluon Project**

With those dependencies and the native library, you will be able to create a new Gluon Project, and add the jars as local dependencies (to the `libs` folder).

As for the native library, it should be added to this path: `src/ios/jniLibs/libCharm.a`.

Update the `build.gradle` script:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
    jcenter()
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-glisten-connect-view:3.0.0'

    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-glisten-ios:3.0.0'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

On your View, retrieve the service and provide some basic UI to call the `play("audio.mp3")`, `pause()`, `resume()` and `stop()` methods:

```
private boolean pause;

public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    AudioService audioService = PlatformFactory.getPlatform().getAudioService();
    final HBox hBox = new HBox(10, 
            MaterialDesignIcon.PLAY_ARROW.button(e -> audioService.play("audio.mp3")),
            MaterialDesignIcon.PAUSE.button(e -> {
                if (!pause) {
                    audioService.pause();
                    pause = true;
                } else {
                    audioService.resume();
                    pause = false;
                }

            }),
            MaterialDesignIcon.STOP.button(e -> audioService.stop()));
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    setCenter(new StackPane(hBox));
}
```

Finally, place an audio file like `audio.mp3`, under `src/ios/assets/audio.mp3`, build and deploy to iOS.

Hopefully, this API will be provided by Charm Down any time soon. Also if you come up with a nice implementation, feel free to share it and create a [Pull Request](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/pull-requests/).

Comment: After applying all of these changes, the app froze. the log has this output : 2016-07-30 12:32:50.769 GluonApp [3146:1115803] Play audio
2016-07-30 12:32:50.770 GluonApp [3146:1115803] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x1d34b64 of class 'Audio' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2016-07-30 12:32:50.770 GluonApp [3146:1115803] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x1d34b64 of class 'Audio' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort

Comment: Make sure you have followed every step, there are many files to modify. Did you manage to build successfully your modified Charm Down? Are you using iOS sdk 9.3?

Comment: I've edited my answer, but with minor changes in `Audio.m`, removing imports and unnecessary `view`.

Comment: I can imagine, it must be quite difficult, but thank you for the immense help! The Gluon Mobile and javafxports libraries have been extremely helpful and thank you for the amazing work on them!

Comment: `AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];`  If you place this code in Audio.m before the AVAudioPlayer object is instantiated, the audio file will play even if the hardware mute button on the device has been pressed.

Comment: Is `src/ios/jniLibs/libCharm.a` still valid path... Should `libLog.a` created by `ios-build.gradle` from http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/ be placed there (inside `GoNativeApp`) - so that `System.loadLibrary("Log)` can find it there?

Comment: Please post a new question.