# JavaFXPorts - Battery consumtion - Screen always on

Tags: java, performance, javafx, javafxports

I've a question about `JavaFXPorts`' battery consumption. On both *Android* and *IOS*, the screen is **always on**. And the phones get quite hot...

When creating a trace dump on Android or looking at the extensive log on IOS, you can see the **`QuantumRenderer`** to be active the whole time (on *IOS* you can see the message `setSwapInterval([0|1])` (OpenGL?) constantly - this could be a lead.

Otherwise: Is it possible, that there's a "always on" flag set? If so: How to turn it off???

Regards,
Daniel

---

**Edit:** As the image below shows, I did a trace (in fact, I did several) of the app running.

[image: App-Trace]

As you can see, there is this ominous Timer active. While in the App there actually is a Timer, I've completely deactivated it's usage, but this *"Timer-0"* thread is still active... Beside the Charm-Down BLE, there are not many threads I'd suspect. And Timer indicates, that something is active repeatedly. Is this a normal Android behaviour, maybe?

Additionally I'd like to state again: I have some JavaFX-Services in the app, but since there is only this one *"Thread-1952"*, I assume those are not the reason...

---

**Edit 2:**

And another image: Detailed method profiling. This *Timer-0* is triggering pulses to the `QuantumToolkit`, which I assume keeps the screen on.

[image: Timer-0 pulsating]

The pulse is done in the big block, starting and ending with a blue small block:

[image: Detailed pulse]

And I've seen the name `MonocleTimer$1.run ()V` pop up... Maybe this is the culprit.

---

**Edit 3:**

Charm Down BLE-Plugin removed completely:

[image]

**Edit 4:**

Some time ago I made an example application for other performance issues.
It shows the exact same behaviour:

https://github.com/bgmf/example

Comment: What do you mean by battery consumption? The Down `Battery` plugin? None of the plugins set the screen always on.

Comment: At the moment, my app stays active on both IOS and Android. In my opinion without that I have done something to do so. This (probably) results in the many `QuantumRenderer` calls and in the end: The phone stays on and the battery drains...

Comment: But are you using the Down plugin?

Comment: yes, its part of the registered plugins: `plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'battery', 'orientation', 'settings', 'browser', 'ble'` (even if I think, I don't need it anymore...)

Comment: I have a test app with all the plugins, including the battery, and both iOS and Android don't stay on, they turn off as usual. Also, the battery relies on callbacks from the native layers, so it is not constantly polling data.

Comment: Hm. Weird. Will need to dig into the code. But I currently don't see, what could cause this. JavaFX services? Their executors? I have to admit, that I have no clue...

Comment: I've updated the question: added a trace (image). I think, I know ***why*** it is happening, but i have no idea how to solve it...

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code. Do you think it is because of the BLE plugin? If you don't use it, still happens? Does this happen to you in other apps?

Comment: No. It's not BLE. Just tried it with the same result. Removed some unused plugins as well. The question is, why this MonocleTimer is called so often. As far as I can see, I have nothing that would trigger this so often. It's not open source, so I can't show you the app - sorry. :-( And this is my first JavaFXPorts app, so no: It's the first, where it's happening.

Comment: Then just try a simple app with the Gluon IDE plugin. You'll see that the app doesn't keep the device on all the time.

Comment: I believe you... So I just re-checked the Example application I created for the text rendering performance issues. It shows the same behaviour (I've added the link to the GitHub repository to the question). *_If_* you want to have a look, I'd be happy... Regardless, it's to late to start the app from sratch, so for now i have to deal with it - and will also try to look into in on the example app - because it's much smaller and better to handle...

Comment: Hm. I created a `SingleViewProject` with the *Gluon Plugin*, using *Eclipse Neon.2* - and it didn't turn off the screen. I used the `androidInstall` task, which. Maybe the debuging?

Comment: What do you mean by debugging? Are you attaching a debugger? Can you run it without it? It should turn off after a short while. Else you have a an issue with your device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135578/discussion-between-dzim-and-jose-pereda).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more tests, cleaned-up build file, I was able to reproduce this reliably only on the Nexus 5. Regardless of whether it is plugin in (debug mode) or not, the display stays on.
On a Nexus 6, this behavior was not reproducible anymore.

I will close this issue, because I believe it's - once again - a device-related issue.