# Gluon iOS audio Player

Tags: ios, audio, gluon-mobile

I've been following various answers to various questions on the subject and I've come to a result and some code which looks like it works. I'm getting stuck with the NSURL part of it. I've got 2 mp3 tracks in the assets folder of my iOS gluon project. I've made the IOSAudioService Class to handle the playback. and I'm passing an argument from the play button in the view to the Play() method. Everything other than the actual file is registering as working. I'm getting an NSError, which from looking at the code is a nil value, so either the argument isn't passing correctly or it can't find the file. Code below.

```
    public AVAudioPlayer backgroundMusic;
private double currentPosition;
NSURL songURL = null;

@Override
public void Play(String filename){
songURL = new NSURL(filename);

try {
        if (backgroundMusic != null) {
            Resume();
        }
        else {
        //Start the audio at the beginning.
        currentPosition = 0;
        backgroundMusic = new AVAudioPlayer(songURL);
        //create the mendia player and assign it to the audio
        backgroundMusic.prepareToPlay();
        backgroundMusic.play();}
        //catch the audio error
    } catch(NSErrorException e) {
        System.out.println("error: " + e);
    }
}
@Override
public void Stop() {
    backgroundMusic.stop();
    backgroundMusic = null;
}
@Override
public void Pause() {
    currentPosition = backgroundMusic.getCurrentTime();
    backgroundMusic.pause();
}
@Override
public void Resume() {
    backgroundMusic.setCurrentTime(currentPosition);
    backgroundMusic.play();
}

try {
        services = (AudioService) Class.forName("com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.ios.IOSAudioService").newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error " + ex);
    }
```

I'm getting the error at the catch block for NSExceptionError e.

```
    if (services != null) {
        final HBox hBox = new HBox(10, 
                MaterialDesignIcon.PLAY_ARROW.button(e -> services.Play("/audio.mp3")),
                MaterialDesignIcon.PAUSE.button(e -> {
                    if (!pause) {
                        services.Pause();
                        pause = true;
                    } else {
                        services.Resume();
                        pause = false;
                    }
                }),
                MaterialDesignIcon.STOP.button(e -> services.Stop()));
        //set the HBox alignment
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.getStyleClass().add("hbox");
        //create and set up a vbox to include the image, audio controls and the text then set the alignment
        final VBox vBox = new VBox(5, Image(), hBox, text1);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setCenter(new StackPane(vBox));
    } else {
        //start an error if service is null
        setCenter(new StackPane(new Label("Only for Android")));
    }
    Services.get(LifecycleService.class).ifPresent(s -> s.addListener(LifecycleEvent.PAUSE, () -> services.Stop()));
}
```

I've also follow the advice on creating the service factory class and the interface from [Audio performance with Javafx for Android (MediaPlayer and NativeAudioService)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828907/audio-performance-with-javafx-for-android-mediaplayer-and-nativeaudioservice/42934078#42934078) taking out the add audio element and I'm intending to do this on a view by view basis if possible.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: I don't have a stacktrace the app doesn't actually crash. I get an error starting with 2000. Details are at work so unavailable until monday now. The error meant the NSURL had a nil value  so resource could not be found or there was a varible wrapping error. I was wondering if i needed to use the NSBundle to find the resource path first, not that I'm sure that is possible/the right answer.

Comment: The error code was OSStatus error 2003334207 I believe.

Comment: If your mp3 file is in the assets folder, probably you don't need the slash. Try `services.Play("audio.mp3")`. Else you can check other questions about the error, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088594/osstatus-error-2003334207-when-using-avaudioplayer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after must fiddling and looking in the Javadocs.Solved by adding/replacing some code with the below.

```
songURL = new NSURL("file:///" + NSBundle.getMainBundle().findResourcePath(filename, "mp3"));
try {
songURL.checkResourceIsReachable();}
catch(NSErrorException d)  {
    System.out.println("Song not found!" + d);
}
```